# Tagging in php and sql

Tags: php, sql

I have the following tables in my database:

thread --- thread_replies --- replies
thread --- thread_tags --- tags

```
thread: id, title, content, created, author_id

thread_tags: id, thread_id, tag_id

tags: id, name
```

I can select tags for a certain thread using the following:

```
   SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tags.name ORDER BY tags.name DESC SEPARATOR ',') AS tags
    FROM tags INNER JOIN thread_tags ON tag_id = tags.id
    INNER JOIN thread ON thread_id = thread.id
    WHERE thread.id = 20
```

However what I want to do is when I select all the threads, I want to select all the tags associated with each thread as well...

I want to build a multidimensional array like the following:

```
    Array
(
    [t_id] => 20
    [title] => this is a title
    [content] => This is content
    [username] => username1
    [a_id] => 35
    [tags] => tag1, tag2, tag3
)
```

I want to know what sql statement I can use to create this for each thread?

So if I select all the threads and their associated authors, how can I also get the tags associated with each thread?

Currently I use this to get each thread and its author:

```
SELECT thread.id AS t_id, thread.title,
                         thread.content, author.username, author.id AS a_id
                         FROM thread INNER JOIN author ON thread.author_id = author.id
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
SELECT distinct thread.title, thread.id as t_id, thread.content, author.username, author.id as a_id,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tags.name ORDER BY tags.name DESC SEPARATOR ',') AS tags
from thread join thread_tags on thread.id = thread_tags.thread_id
join tags on thread_tags.tag_id = tags.id
inner join author on author.id = thread.author_id
group by thread.title
```